# Recurring variadic template class parameters

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I would like a variadic template class (with, say `N` template parameters) to define `N` member functions, each one taking a single parameter of type from the parameters list. I tried this :

```
template<class Derived, class... DerivedOthers>
class VtfVisitor : public VtfVisitor<DerivedOthers...>
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Derived& derived) = 0;
};

template<class Derived>
class VtfVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Derived& derived) = 0;
};
```

Which does not work as I cannot redefine a template class. Then I tried solution proposed by Bo :

```
template<class Derived, class... DerivedOthers>
class VtfVisitor : public VtfVisitor<DerivedOthers...>
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Derived& derived) VISITOR_CVQ = 0;
};

template<class Derived>
class VtfVisitor<Derived>
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Derived& derived) VISITOR_CVQ = 0;
};
```

Which still does not work: when trying this with `VtfVisitor<D1,D2>`, member function `visit(D2&)` is not defined in the instanciated template class (while `visit(D1&)` is well defined).

How could I get this to work as expected ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the ellipsis outside the *template argument list*:

```
template<class Derived, class... DerivedOthers>
class VtfVisitor : public VtfVisitor<DerivedOthers>...
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Derived& derived) = 0;
};
```

---

As an example, if `DerivedOthers...` is `{int, char, float}`, you will get the following expansion:

```
class VtfVisitor : public VtfVisitor<char>, VtfVisitor<float>
{
public:
    virtual void visit(int& derived) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Though this would work, this would create a class with multiple inheritance, wich I would like to avoid. However, your solution works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler believes that you are redeclaring the same class with different number of parameters.

To create a specialization for the single argument case, you have to specify that after the class name:

```
template<class Derived>
class VtfVisitor<Derived>
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Derived& derived) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Oh, yes... it is a specialization. It is confusing, as the same pattern works with template functions wich, in this case, defines a new function and not a specialization. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, functions can be overloaded, classes cannot.

Comment: Ehm, actually, this does not work as expected. When I define a class inheriting from `VtfVisitor<T1,T2>`, then member function `virtual void VtfVisitor<T1,T2>::visit(D2&)` is not defined. What is this not working ?

Comment: How do you decide if it is defined or not? Members of a templated base class are not visible in the derived class, unless imported with `using` or accessed with `this->`. Especially with specializations around, the compiler cannot assume that all base classes have the same members.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks.It's quite confusing though, as `VtfVisitor<T1,T2>::visit(D1&)` is well defined in the derived class, while `VtfVisitor<T1,T2>::visit(D2&)` is not...